# How to get the real time of recurring events?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I use following method to fetch all events for calendars:

```
public Cursor getEventsCursor(Context context) {        
    long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long begin = curr - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 30; // - 30 days
    long end = curr + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 30;   // + 30 days

    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    String selection = Events.VISIBLE + "= ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"1"};
    String order = Events.DTSTART + " DESC";

    Uri.Builder builder = Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, begin);
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, end);

    return cr.query(builder.build(), EVENT_PROJECTION, 
            selection, selectionArgs, order);
}
```

It works, but I get the initial time for all recurring events!

**Logs**

```
Feeder milestone; eventId: 12;  date=2012-12-06 11:00:00  // initial time
Feeder milestone; eventId: 23;  date=2012-12-06 11:00:00
Feeder milestone; eventId: 178; date=2012-12-06 11:00:00
Feeder milestone; eventId: 180; date=2012-12-06 11:00:00
```

How to get the real times of recurring events?

**Example**: if recurring event `Feeder milestone` is 2-weekly event, I expect:

```
Feeder milestone; eventId: 12;  date=2014-08-03 11:00:00
Feeder milestone; eventId: 23;  date=2014-08-27 11:00:00
Feeder milestone; eventId: 178; date=2014-09-11 11:00:00
Feeder milestone; eventId: 180; date=2014-09-25 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Calendar Provider documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), there are 3 things related to `Events`, and one of them is `Instances`.

> Events: This table holds the event-specific information. Each row in this table has the **information for a single event**—for example, event title, location, start time, end time, and so on. The event can occur one-time or can recur multiple times. Attendees, reminders, and extended properties are stored in separate tables. They each have an EVENT_ID that references the _ID in the Events table.
>
> Instances: This table holds **the start and end time for each occurrence of an event**. Each row in this table represents a single event occurrence. For one-time events there is a 1:1 mapping of instances to events. For recurring events, multiple rows are automatically generated that correspond to multiple occurrences of that event.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

In case of recurring event, `Events.DTSTART` refers to the starting time of *whole* events.

On the other hand, `Instances.BEGIN` and `Instances.END` refer to the starting and ending time of *each occurrence* of an event.

In general case, always use `Instances.BEGIN` to get the starting time of all events (whether recurring or not) conveniently.

Comment: Is it possible to get `duration` for event without query to `Instances`? When I create event I set **start** and **end** and according to these values duration calculated for all instances. Why I can not get this information from event (or maybe I am doing something wrong)? Please check the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221843/why-duration-is-null-for-recurrent-event-in-android