# Why duration is NULL for recurrent event in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-calendar, calendarcontract

I try to implement one way synchronization with android calendar events (I need original events - not event instances). So, I have the following query:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                    CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
                    CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DURATION
            };
String selection = null;
String[] args = new String[0];
String sort = CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " ASC";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, args, sort);
```

According to [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html) for recurrent events `dtstart` and `duration` are required but when I create event through Google calendar and receive it later in my code I have `dtend = 0` and `duration = null`.

```
Integer dtend = cursor.getLong(2);
String duration = cursor.getString(4);
```

Why it may happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an issue with indexes in my original application. `CalendarContract.Events.DURATION` column solves the problem. It has single event duration in `RFC2445` format. I just need to parse it.